# Convert mysql query logic to Laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder

I am trying to convert my mysql query logic to Laravel query builder. I I have no Idea how to convert it as laravel query.

my query logic is

```
SELECT id,name,
case 
    when visibility_status = '1' 
    then 'Visible' 
    when visibility_status = '0' 
    then 'Invisible'
    end as visibility_status FROM `flowers`
```

generally I write a select query using query builder but cant implement above logic

```
$result = DB::table('flowers')
        ->select('flowers.id as id', 'flowers.name as name',
'flowers.visibility_status as visibility_status');
```

Comment: A different approach might be to add a table to decode the value and then join to it. So you'd have a small table that just had two rows and two columns: `0|Invisible, 1|Visible`. Then in either plain SQL or in (non-raw-query) Laravel Query Builder you'd just join from flowers to the decode table and read the value from there. Alternatively, just read the 0 and the 1 and decode them directly in the Laravel View where you output them, assuming that's what you're doing with them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try This

```
$users = DB::table('flowers')
->select(["id", "name",
      DB::raw("
       case 
          when visibility_status = '1' 
          then 'Visible' 
          when visibility_status = '0' 
          then 'Invisible'
          end as visibility_status
    ")])->get();
```

Here is the reference for it
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: To note: You'd need PHP `5.4 >=` to make this work I believe?

Comment: @MackieeE PHP >= 5.4 is a requirement for Laravel anyways