# how to convert inner query in select to eloquent laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a query like this..

```
select *,
case l.user_type 
when '0' then 
(select CONCAT(first_name,'',last_name) from users where id=l.user_id) 
when '1' then 
(select party_name from tbl_partys where id=l.user_id) 
end as user_name 
from tbl_leased_comm l 
where l.user_id=$party and l.user_id=$user_id 
order by l.updated_at desc
```

How to convert this query to laravel query
help me, anyone...

Comment: Can you please show your user_type, tbl_partys and  tbl_leased_comm Model and it's relation

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000585/convert-mysql-query-logic-to-laravel-query-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it works for me

as,

```
DB::table('tbl_leased_comm')
            ->select(["*",
                  DB::raw("case tbl_leased_comm.user_type when '0' then (select CONCAT(first_name,'',last_name) from users where id=tbl_leased_comm.user_id) when '1' then (select party_name from tbl_partys where id=tbl_leased_comm.user_id) end as user_name")])
            ->where('tbl_leased_comm.user_id','=',$party )
            ->where('tbl_leased_comm.user_id','=',$user_id)
            ->orderBy('tbl_leased_comm.updated_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Thanks a lot..

reference link:[Convert mysql query logic to Laravel query builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000585/convert-mysql-query-logic-to-laravel-query-builder)